# Ruby gem dependency loading

Tags: ruby, rubygems, acts-as-list

I'm putting some shared models for a rails app inside it's own gem. It's just models, so I'm not using an engine. Getting it set up seemed to work fine until I added the "acts_as_list" gem.

```
# gem - domain.gemspec
spec.add_dependency "acts_as_list"

# gem - lib/domain.rb
require "acts_as_list"

# gem - lib/domain/models/page.rb
acts_as_list scope: [:ancestry]
```

This works fine in the console for my gem, I can run methods specific to acts_as_list as usual. However, when I add my gem to another project, it gives me an error.

```
# project - Gemfile
gem "www_domain", path: "../www_domain"

Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'domain'.
NoMethodError: undefined method `acts_as_list' for #<Class:0x0055da70121ab0>
/home/shaun/sites/demo/domain/lib/domain/models/page.rb:32:in `<class:Page>'
```

Is there something special I have to do in this case to access the `acts_as_list` method because my model is inside a gem?

**Update:** Here is my complete `lib/domain.rb` file for the gem:

```
require "yaml"
require "active_record"
require "acts_as_list"
require "ancestry"

# rbfiles = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "lib", "**", "*.rb")
# Dir.glob(rbfiles).each do |file|
#   require file.gsub("lib/", "")
# end

module Domain
  # Your code goes here...
  def self.root
    File.dirname(__dir__)
  end

  def self.db_config
    YAML.load_file("#{Domain.root}/db/config.yml")["development"]
  end
end

require "domain/version"
require "domain/models/page"
require "domain/models/menu"
require "domain/models/article"
require "domain/models/page_part"
```

I can use `acts_as_list` and `ancestry` methods in the console of my gem (running `bin/console` from the gem directory). But the project console (running `bundle exec rails console` from the project directory) will not start because of the gem error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This might result from a load order issue if the model being required before the `require :acts_as_list` statement. Check to see if the gem specifies the load order. If not, you could try something like:

```
# gem - lib/domain.rb
require "acts_as_list"

require "models/page"
```

If the load order is unclear, I find it helpful to simply add a

```
puts __FILE__
```

at the top of the relevant source files.

Comment: Please take a look at my update which includes my entire `lib/domain.rb` file. `require "acts_as_list"` does come before `require "domain/models/page"`. I also tried putting `require "acts_as_list"` on the top of the `domain/models.page.rb` file, before the class, but it didn't change the error coming from my project.